# Create iOS / Android shortcut or APP for a website

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, android-webview

I have been asked to make an iOS / Android app that simply opens a website on full screen.
I have told them that, by using the iOS / Android native option to "Add to Homescreen" would accomplish the needs, but they insist on making it completelly automatic for the end-user.

Am I doomed to make both Apps for this need? Is there any way to "automatically create" or "share" an already created homescreen shortcut?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way for the web site to create it's shortcut on the user's device. It is quite same as adding to favorites - website can't add itself to favorites. Only user can do that.

Comment: FYI - Apple will not approve an app that simply displays a website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doomed to make two apps, but you can start with a cross platform framework that can output to both platforms, allowing you to write it once. From how you describe this project I recommend starting with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org).

As maddy points out in the comment, an app that simply displays a website will be rejected by Apple. Yet if you encapsulate them website inside Cordova app, where the app need not access the website, or only access a website for updated information you will probably be approved.